# "Variable cannot be used as a constant" c++ array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I am struggling with C++. I learned Java before and i think it is much easier, tbh. Currently, I am trying to code a counting sort algorithm with c++. I want to get the maximum of my array to declare my helping array with the size = maximum +1; I tried several ways but nothing works. It always shows "variable cannot be used as a constant". I also have found a code which does the same as mine but seems like to work. Can anyone give me some hints or solutions?

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


int getMax(int arr[], int size) 
{
    int max = arr[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < sizeof(arr); i++) {
        if (arr[i] > max) {
            max = arr[i];                                   
        }
    }

    return max;
}
void countingSort(int *arr, int size)
{
    int max = getMax(arr, size);
    int hilfsArr[max + 1];

}
```

Comment: For array of dynamic size, just use `std::vector`

Comment: `int hilfsArr[max + 1];` is not legal in standard `c++`. Also `for (int i = 1; i < sizeof(arr); i++) {` is not going to work. `sizeof(arr)` will be the size of a pointer. Interestingly you have a `int size` parameter.

Comment: `getMax` is also broken, `sizeof(arr)` should be `size`.

Comment: Moving to a second language is always hard, because you've developed habits that work in your first language  but don't work in the second. Moving to a third language is much easier, because you saw the pitfalls when you made the earlier move.,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**You can not use variables for compile time array size** simply because compiler has no way of knowing what the value returned by your `getMax` function will be ...

You need to use dynamic arrays in cases like this...

```
void countingSort(int *arr, int size)
    {
    int max = getMax(arr, size);
    int *hilfsArr=new int[max + 1]; // allocate

    ... here put the rest of your code for this function

    delete[] hilfsArr; // free before exiting function
    }
```

Comment: Please don't teach direct dynamic allocation when a `vector` will do.

Answer (score 2):

For array of dynamic size, just use `std::vector`, something like:

```
void countingSort(int *arr, int size)
{
    std::vector<int> counter(*std::max_element(arr, arr + size));
    // ...
}
```